# Set inputrangefilter for EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I currently have this class below. It can set an InputrangeFilter for any number and an edittext will always be between these two numbers. Now I have thought that it would be useful to make a value that is greater than max be automatically replaced my the maximum. I have tried

```
if (input>max) {return String.valueOf(max);}
```

But this just writes max into the Textedit instead of clearing the input before. Is there anything I can do to fix that?

```
public class InputFilterMinMax implements InputFilter {

        private int min, max;

        public InputFilterMinMax(int min, int max) {
            this.min = min;
            this.max = max;
        }

        public InputFilterMinMax(String min, String max) {
            this.min = Integer.parseInt(min);
            this.max = Integer.parseInt(max);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            try {
                // Remove the string out of destination that is to be replaced
                String newVal = dest.toString().substring(0, dstart) + dest.toString().substring(dend, dest.toString().length());
                // Add the new string in
                newVal = newVal.substring(0, dstart) + source.toString() + newVal.substring(dstart, newVal.length());
                int input = Integer.parseInt(newVal);
                if (isInRange(min, max, input))
                    return null;
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { }
            return "";
        }

        private boolean isInRange(int a, int b, int c) {
            return b > a ? c >= a && c <= b : c >= b && c <= a;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is 'isInRange(min,max,input)' your method mentioned above?

Comment: Bsaically yes, I don't need a check for a minimum number.

Comment: Try to put a debug breakpoint inside your method, and check the value of max before you cast it to string from the watcher console inside the debugger.

Comment: Anyway, if the value is in range you return null, but if the value is not in range, you are returning nothing